# How to make Rijndael CBC mode work in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, aes, rijndael

I'm trying to make rijndael work in CBC mode. I'm not exactly sure how should I do it. I think problem in my current code is that the stream is initialized every time in the beginning of encryption, so no avalanche effect occurs (same data is encrypted twice and the output of those two encryption is the same which it should not be).

I tried to initialize the cryptostream only once but then my coded crashed because the canwrite property of cryptostream goes to false after the first write to the cryptostream.

Here is the code what I have now:

```
Sub Main()

        Dim rij As New RijndaelManaged
        Dim iv(15) As Byte
        Dim key(15) As Byte
        Dim secret() As Byte = {59, 60, 61}

        Dim cs As ICryptoTransform
        Dim cstream As CryptoStream

        Dim out() As Byte
        Dim NewRandom As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider()

        NewRandom.GetBytes(iv)
        NewRandom.GetBytes(key)

        rij = New RijndaelManaged()

        rij.KeySize = 128
        rij.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7

        rij.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

        rij.IV = iv
        rij.Key = key
        cs = rij.CreateEncryptor()

        Dim ms_in As New MemoryStream
        cstream = New CryptoStream(ms_in, cs, CryptoStreamMode.Write)


        Using cstream
            cstream.Write(secret, 0, 3)
        End Using

        out = ms_in.ToArray
        Console.WriteLine(ArrayToString(out, out.Length))
        Erase out

        ms_in = New MemoryStream
        cstream = New CryptoStream(ms_in, cs, CryptoStreamMode.Write)


        Using cstream
            cstream.Write(secret, 0, 3)
        End Using

        out = ms_in.ToArray
        Console.WriteLine(ArrayToString(out, out.Length))

    End Sub
```

and the conversion function to convert an array to string

```
 Public Function ArrayToString(ByVal bytes() As Byte, ByVal length As Integer) As String

        If bytes.Length = 0 Then Return String.Empty
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder(length)

        Dim k As Integer = length - 1
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To k
            sb.Append(Chr(bytes(i)))
        Next


        Return sb.ToString()

    End Function
```

---

This is what I need:

```
    cs = rij.CreateEncryptor()
    Dim ms_in As New MemoryStream
    cstream = New CryptoStream(ms_in, cs, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

    Using cstream
        cstream.Write(secret, 0, 3) 'encrypt
    End Using

    out = ms_in.ToArray
    Console.WriteLine(ArrayToString(out, out.Length)) 'see the encrypted message
    Erase out

    Using cstream
        cstream.Write(secret, 0, 3) 'encrypt, this will crash here and this is the problem I'm trying to solve
    End Using

    out = ms_in.ToArray
    Console.WriteLine(ArrayToString(out, out.Length)) 'see the encrypted message this should not be the same as the first one
```

Comment: The latest code you added is not correct. A `Using` clause calls Dispose() on the object being used. It is not possible to re-use the object after calling Dispose(). For correct usage of `Using`, see the code I posted below.

Comment: Ok, so actually I should not use using-clause if I want to reuse cryptostream. I need to write to the same cryptostream again to get chaining effect and using-clause disposes the object which is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Sub Run()
    Dim key() As Byte = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}

    Dim plaintext1 As Byte() = {59, 60, 61}

    Dim plaintext2 As Byte() = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15, _
                             0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15, _
                             0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15, _
                             0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 _
                             }

    Roundtrip(plaintext1, key)
    System.Console.WriteLine()
    Roundtrip(plaintext2, key)

End Sub


Public Sub Roundtrip(ByRef plaintext As Byte(), ByRef key As Byte())

    Dim rij As New RijndaelManaged
    Dim iv(15) As Byte

    Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform
    Dim decryptor As ICryptoTransform

    Dim out() As Byte

    'Dim NewRandom As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider()
    'NewRandom.GetBytes(iv)
    'NewRandom.GetBytes(key)

    Console.WriteLine("Original:")
    Console.WriteLine(ArrayToString(plaintext))
    System.Console.WriteLine()

    rij = New RijndaelManaged()
    rij.KeySize = key.Length * 8  ' 16 byte key == 128 bits
    rij.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
    rij.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
    rij.IV = iv
    rij.Key = key
    encryptor = rij.CreateEncryptor()

    Using msIn = New MemoryStream

        Using cstream = New CryptoStream(msIn, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            cstream.Write(plaintext, 0, plaintext.Length)
        End Using

        out = msIn.ToArray
        Console.WriteLine("Encrypted:")
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", ArrayToString(out))
        System.Console.WriteLine()

    End Using

    decryptor = rij.CreateDecryptor()
    Using msIn = New MemoryStream

        Using cstream = New CryptoStream(msIn, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            cstream.Write(out, 0, out.Length)
        End Using

        out = msIn.ToArray
        Console.WriteLine("Decrypted:  ")
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", ArrayToString(out))
        System.Console.WriteLine()

    End Using

End Sub


Public Shared Function ArrayToString(ByVal bytes As Byte()) As String

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To bytes.Length-1
        if (i <> 0 AND i mod 16 = 0) Then
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine)
        End If
        sb.Append(System.String.Format("{0:X2} ", bytes(i)))
    Next

    Return sb.ToString().Trim()

End Function
```

I made these basic changes to get it to work:

- create a Decryptor
- properly manage buffers and streams (see the `Using` clauses I added)

I also re-organized a little, and modified your code slightly to use a constant IV (all zeros) and use a constant key.  This is so that you can get repeatable results from one run to the next. In a real app you would use a randomized IV and use a password-derived key.  (See [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx))

---

ok, that allows the code to compile. I think you want to see the effect of chaining. That is not  so easy, but maybe something like this will show you what you want to see:

```
        For i As Integer = 1 To 2
            Using ms = New MemoryStream
                Using cstream = New CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                    For j As Integer = 1 To i
                        cstream.Write(plaintext, 0, plaintext.Length)
                    Next j
                End Using
                out = ms.ToArray
                Console.WriteLine("Encrypted (cycle {0}):", i)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", ArrayToString(out))
                System.Console.WriteLine()

            End Using
        Next i
```

Comment: Cheeso, that does not answer my question. If I use your code and do "RoundTrip(plaintext1, key)" twice the encrypted text is the same which it should not be since it is CBC mode, no avalanche effect. (I'm using rijndael to secure communications)

Comment: I misunderstood the question, then. If I understand what you are saying in your comment, your assumption is incorrect. You appear to assume that using Rijndael twice in the same app will result in chaining. This is not correct. The reason the cryptotext is the same in this app: you are using the same IV, the same key, and the same plaintext. To check for the chaining, you need to encrypt the plaintext twice in succession *using the same CryptoStream instance*.  IE, initialize it once, then encrypt a text twice. The cryptotext from the first cycle will be different than the crypto for the 2nd.

Comment: In pseudo it would look like this: crypto-object.init(key,iv) -> encrypt("hello", crypto-object) -> encrypt("hello", crypto-object) => should result different encrypted output. (I'm not sure if you meant like that.) I just can't do it, If I comment out the second cstream initialization in my code it crashes to "stream does not support writing" error. This is my problem what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding about how the .NET classes work. As I said above, You can achieve what you want by encrypting the same plaintext twice in succession, using the same CryptoStream. Have you tried that? When I do it I get different cryptotext. Encrypting the same plaintext with two unique instances of the CryptoStream will produce identical ciphertext, by design.  It would be very bad if it produced different cipher text.

Comment: I know and I have tried :) and yes I know that two unique instances of the cryptostream will produce identical ciphertext.  The problem is that I do not know how to use same cryptostream twice. Can you post how to do it that would solve my problem?

Comment: check the additional code, above. I really don't understand why you call this *a problem* - it seems to me you are exploring AES encryption, but you are not actually experiencing a *problem*, per se.

Comment: I can not use the encryption as a loop because I'm not sending the same message between a client and a server. See the new code I posted in my first post, that is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: In addition, when I solve the problem of reusing the same cryptostream instance then I can write a function that does the encryption.

Comment: you seem to keep moving the bar. Your question was "How to use AES CBC mode in VB?"  In the first case, your code did not run correctly.  I fixed that, I showed you how to use Using clauses properly. Then you stated another problem, something you were wondering about (CBC chaining). I illustrated that for you. Now you have another problem. Maybe ask another question, eh?

Comment: I'm sorry for that and all the confusion. I was trying to make you understand my problem but I have failed and confused you more.